# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 (MD101) makes weird sound on wake up/start up

Tags: macbook-pro

I have this weird sound when I open up MacBook or when I run it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIUVbq25uvY

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem as that is the sound the SuperDrive makes when power is applied to it. I found it quite annoying on my first MacBook Pro however my current MacBook Pro doesn't have an internal SuperDrive although the external one make the same sound.

There is nothing you can do to solve it as it's that way by design.

Answer (score 1):

@user3439894 is right. What you can do is  replace the superdrive with a second hard drive. Thats what i had done with most my older macbooks

You can find instructions here 
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive/13787